# Having some trouble on how to Build MEX-function from C/C++ or Fortran source code in MATLAB2015 ubuntu

Tags: compiling, c++, matlab

please can anyone help me out.

I am trying to check the example provided in MATLAB documentation about how  Build MEX-function from C/C++ or Fortran source code here https://ww2.mathworks.cn/help/matlab/ref/mex.html?requestedDomain=en

After creating all the directory required and copying the function yprime.c to the directory, I run this command in the matlab command

mex yprime.c

I am getting the following error

Error using mex
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lstdc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

What are the possible causes and solutions to this errors?

Regards

Comment: Is that the entire message? I am trying to understand why it would be trying to link the C++ standard library for a `.c` file. What version of Ubuntu and what version of MATLAB are you using, and how did you configure the C/C++ compilers for MATLAB?

Comment: @steeldriver , I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and MATLAB 2015a, and my OS type is 64bit. For the compiler, I just updated the older version of the gcc to gcc 4.7 and set it as a default compiler.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install `-dev` packages for `stdc++` library:

```
sudo apt install libstdc++-4.8-dev libstdc++-5-dev
```

and do not forget to install `build-essential` package.

Comment: I have tried your suggestion, but the error still exists.